# $\max <x,q>$ when $x \in H$ Hilbert and $q \in A^\bot$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

How can I find $\max \langle x,q \rangle$ where $x$ is fixed in a Hilbert space $H$ and $q$ runs over $ A^\bot$ with $\|q\|=1$, $A$ a proper nontrivial subspace? (Here we assume $x \notin A, A^\bot$.)

Is $q$ the projection of $x$ onto $A^\bot$ (and then normalized)? How can I prove this? Any essential suggestion?

Additional consideration : we consider both $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ for scalar fields.

Comment: $A$ is closed ?

Comment: even if A is not closed, $A^\perp$ is always closed

Comment: $q$ should not be the projection. Think about the case $\mathbb{R}^2$, with $A$ being the line $y = -x$ and $A^\perp$ the line $y = x$. Then if $x$ is say, the unit vector $(0,1)$, then $q$ should be the unit vector pointing in the direction $(-1,-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **real** Hilbert, $A^\perp$ is closed subspace so that we
have $$ H = A^\perp \oplus W,\ (q\in )W^\perp=A^\perp $$

Hence $x=x_{w} + x_{w^\perp} $ so that $$ <x,q>=<x_{w^\perp},q > $$

Define $$ f : W^\perp \rightarrow {\bf R},\ f(q)=<q,x_{w^\perp}>
$$

Then  $$| f(q)| \leq \parallel q \parallel
 \parallel x_{w^\perp} \parallel $$ so that $${\rm max}_{\parallel q \parallel =1}
 \ |f(q)| \leq  \parallel x_{w^\perp} \parallel  $$

Let $q= \frac{ x_{w^\perp}  }{\parallel x_{w^\perp}
\parallel }$ Then $$f(q) =  \parallel x_{w^\perp} \parallel  $$